# Using DAO servlets and MYSQL having trouble getting a return from the query, stack trace returning null

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, dao

All of my single function servlets (pretty much only updates to the DB) are working. However I'm getting into a more complicated area where I need to query the database pull a value out and update based on the value returned. I'm a bit confused on what I am doing wrong, there is no stack trace returned, however I'm getting a null pointer exception. The code is as follows.

The problem I am currently having is the query of the DB findbyusername method is returning a null value and immediately jumping to my catch in my servlet.

This is the userDAO

```
public interface UserDAO {

 List<User> findAll();
 User findById(String id);
 User findByUserName(String username);
 User findByUserName(String username, Connection conn)throws SQLException;}
```

This is the method being devloped in mysqluserdao.

```
@Override
public User findByUserName(String username, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    java.sql.PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs =null;
    try {
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT FROM userdetails where User_Name =?");
        st.setString(1, username);
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(rs.getString("User_Name"));
        user.setFirstName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
        user.setLastName(rs.getString("Last_Name"));
        user.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("Email_Address"));
        user.setType(rs.getString("Type"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        return user;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }


}
```

and this is the servlet where I am attempting to query pull out a value, and then update a different table.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //create connection with work object and make strings to do the work
    Confirmation work = new Confirmation();
    String confirmation = "You have succsessfully rented out the vehicle";

    String carid = req.getParameter("id");
    String username = req.getParameter("User_Name");

    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        //connect with the DB
        conn = DBConnector.createConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        UserDAO userDao = new MySQLUserDAO();

        User user = userDao.findByUserName(username, conn); 
        user.setCarRental(carid);
        userDao.updateUser(user.getId(), user, conn);

        CarDAO carDao = new MySQLCarDAO();
        Car car = carDao.findById(carid, conn);
        car.setAvailable("Unavailable");
        carDao.updateCar(car.getId(), car, conn);}
```

Comment: I think you never created a `PreparedStatement st` inside your `findByUserName`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the prerpareStatement. You need to first create it, then add the value and then execute it.

```
@Override
public User findByUserName(String username, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    ResultSet rs =null;
    try {
        st = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM userdetails where User_Name = ?");
        st.setString(1, username);
        rs = st.executeQuery();
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName(rs.getString("User_Name"));
        user.setFirstName(rs.getString("First_Name"));
        user.setLastName(rs.getString("Last_Name"));
        user.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("Email_Address"));
        user.setType(rs.getString("Type"));
        user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
        return user;
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: This totally right in the aspect of doing that however I seem to be getting a null return still I'm not sure what exactly is causing this.

Comment: Where are you getting the null ?

Comment: when I got through the dao and hit the prepared statement it returns null, I do not get a result set back, I double checked the table and spelling. it says I have some kind of a sql syntax error.

Comment: Yes the sentence should be SELECT * FROM userdetails where User_Name = ? You need to add * to tell sql what you want to receive, in this case all the columns.

Comment: Fix this thank you again now I'm getting a NullPointer with no stack track information it immediatly goes to a catch after the statement as if result set doesnt exist

Comment: Replace throw e; with System.out.println(e) and tell me  what u get.

Comment: I got a no expliscit return statment,

Comment: Do you have the stack trace? Whith that I can try to help you a little more. I updated the code, never catch Exception use the concrete exception. Catching exception can hide problems in execution and should always be avoided.

Comment: I created a database with the data of the example and it works perfectly, maybe the trace can provide something new.